# how to find combination of different rows in Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a sheet in which i have 6 columns, A-B-C are group1 and D-E-F are group2. I want to find out whether there exist a particular row for which group1's value is same as group2.
ie. suppose group1 has,

A1-Orange, B1-4, C1-ABC

and group2 has,

D1-Orange, E1-4, F1-ABC

then 1st row should be highlighted?

I have searched, but i dont seem to find ifmatch for combination of columns. Is there any way to do it? Thank you for your suggestions and answers

this is my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_p5a5uGq1UmgdV4Efn3JArC7CMfNcs_1TiEVOzcOPU/edit?usp=sharing

where group1 is B-C-D and group2 is J-K-L.

as the above sheet states line 1 of group1 is similar to line 99 if group2 , then they should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure if you can add a helper column, but you can look at this:

[image]

The helper column just has

```
=D1&E1&F1
```

while the match finds the position of the matching value.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the range, then in Format | Conditional Formatting enter a custom formula of

```
=join("|",$A1:$C1)=join("|",$D1:$F1)
```

and choose a fill colour.

To search in other rows, you can just use COUNTIFS:

```
=countifs($D:$D,$A1,$E:$E,$B1,$F:$F,$C1)
```

And to check back the other way

```
=countifs($A:$A,$D1,$B:$B,$E1,$C:$C,$F1)
```

Comment: this will highlight only if values in 1st row of group1 match values of 1st row in group2.but what if values in group1 1st row, mtches values in group2 450th row??